# (Roblox) " attempt to index number with 'Value' " and " Value is not a valid member of LocalScript "

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm new in Roblox I don't know what I'm doing wrong,

Why do I get this error?
attempt to index number with 'Value
Script:

```
local milk = game.ReplicatedStorage.Milk
local price = 10

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    
    if milk >= price.Value then
        milk = milk - price.Value
        price = price.Value + 10
    else
        print("error")
    end
end)
```

Why do I get this error?
Value is not a valid member of LocalScript
Script:

```
local price = script.Parent.Parent.BuyButton:FindFirstChild("shopSystem")

while true do
    script.Parent.Parent.PriceText.Text = price.Value .. " Milk"
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because you are attempting to index a number with Value.

```
 if milk >= price.Value then
        milk = milk - price.Value
        price = price.Value + 10
```

`price` is a number value You cannot index numbers.

Use

```
if milk >= price then
        milk = milk - price
        price = price + 10
```

Assuming milk is some Roblox type like IntValue and not a native Lua number you should use milk.Value for any calculations.
if milk.Value >= price then
milk.Value = milk.Value - price
price = price + 10

### Second error

```
local price = script.Parent.Parent.BuyButton:FindFirstChild("shopSystem")
```

Here you assign a LocalScript to `price`. Then you attempt to index that LocalScript with `Value`.  LocalScript does not have a `Value` field.

Don't do `price.Value` to avoid that error. Also the naming is not very meaningful. Why would you name a LocalScript price?

And don't run your code in an infinite while loop

Comment: Hi Thanks for help but now i got this new two errors: "attempt to concatenate Instance with string" and "attempt to compare number <= Instance" I dont know why? can you help me with this? Thanks

Comment: no sorry, you should learn Lua. what you're doing here doesn't make any sense. you cannot write random code and hope it will work somehow. these error messages are very trivial mistakes due to the fact that you don't know anything about Lua's basic operations and types.

Comment: Hi, I know a little Lua, I started with unity so I know a little C# and i try to program Lua with what i know from C#

Answer (score 0):

Is milk a int? If so try this:

```
local milk = game.ReplicatedStorage.Milk.Value
local price = 10

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    
    if milk >= price.Value then
        milk = milk - price.Value
        price = price.Value + 10
    else
        print("error")
    end
end)
```